# No module named os found -- Django, mod_wsgi, Apache 2.2

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up apache, mod_wsgi, and django. I'm getting an internal server error with this in my apache error log:

```
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=2893): Target WSGI script '/django/internal/django-development.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=2893): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/django/internal/django-development.wsgi'.
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error]   File "/django/internal/django-development.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error]     import sys, os
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] ImportError: No module named os
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=2893): Target WSGI script '/django/internal/django-development.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=2893): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/django/internal/django-development.wsgi'.
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error]   File "/django/internal/django-development.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error]     import sys, os
[Wed Jun 22 21:31:55 2011] [error] ImportError: No module named os
```

django-development.wsgi

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

path = '/django/internal'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'internal.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Please let me know if there's anything (configuration files, for example) I can post to help you help me diagnose this problem.

*edit:*

this is odd, considering I thought I set my default python version to 2.5.., and ran ./configure with the python2.5 as a parameter

```
$otool -L mod_wsgi.somod_wsgi.so:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.10)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python (compatibility version 2.6.0, current version 2.6.1)
```

and

```
LoadModule wsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /django/internal/django-development.wsgi
```

*edit:*

Ah, it looks like a bad configuration file was being imported. I've gotten it to now give me the following output. Progress:

```
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:28 2011] [error] Exception ImportError: 'No module named atexit' in 'garbage collection' ignored
Fatal Python error: unexpected exception during garbage collection
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:28 2011] [error] Exception ImportError: 'No module named atexit' in 'garbage collection' ignored
Fatal Python error: unexpected exception during garbage collection
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.5.4.
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.6.1.
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jun 22 23:04:29 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 22 23:06:04 2011] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /django/internal/django-development.wsgi
```

*edit*

So, I'd still like to figure out how to make mod_wsgi run python 2.5 instead of 2.6 -- this is what's causing me my big issues right now. Beyond that, it should just be tweaking the apache configuration.

Comment: What version of python? Can you `import os` from a normal python interpreter?

Comment: Version 2.5 -- and yes, I can.

Comment: Can you include a list of files that are in the same directory as `django-development.wsgi`?

Comment: It's actually my entire django site -- should I put it in a separate directory?

Comment: It seems that your python installation doesn't have the `os` module installed. That is a problem with your python installation. Which OS and python are you using?

Comment: I can't tell until I see what files are there :)

Comment: ehhh I don't think I can.. it's kind of proprietary what I'm working on.. don't think the big guys upstairs would approve. What are you trying to figure out? Maybe I can answer it for you.

Comment: @rafalotufo if you look at my previous comment, i can import it just fine in the python shell. I am running OS X and Apple's out-of-the-box Python 2.5 installation

Comment: MacOS X 10.6 has Python 2.6 not 2.5. What MacOS X version are you using?

Comment: Add the output of running 'otool -L mod_wsgi.so' and also the mod_wsgi configuration you put in Apache. Also make sure you disable mod_python if you are also loading that into Apache.

Comment: MacOS X comes with Python 2.4, 2.5, and 2.6 -- 2.6 is default, but I (think) that I changed the default to 2.5 -- whenever I pull up the shell, that's what it tells me that it's using. anyway, [output above]

Comment: @Brain D please let me know that wether you are using virtualenv or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_wsgi for some reason cannot see your Py2.5 library. I would suggest checking the value of [WSGIPythonPath](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) and make sure it points to something like /usr/lib/python2.5

Comment: I put `WSGIPythonPath /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5` in httpd.conf, restarted apache, but still the same result (and same output as before with the otool command).

Comment: to be clear: WSGIPythonPath is not the path to the python binary, it is a search path to the python modules directory. the first directory in the ':' separated list should be the directory that has os.py in it. go [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) for more info.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying -- I've modified it to include /usr/lib/python2.5 (and I checked to make sure that was correct), yet it still feels the need to run with 2.6 for some reason.

Comment: Can you think of any other reason it would be neglecting my WSGIPythonPath? Does it need to be perhaps above a particular configuration in httpd.conf?

Comment: shouldn't need to be. try having the first line of your wsgi script be "import sys; raise Exception(sys.path)". This will force it to print your python module path/log it. then you can see if it has the correct directories loaded.