# Django, mod_wsgi, Apache: Internal server error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have configured Django 1.4 with mod_wsgi 2.0 and apache 2.2.3 in a Redhat server.
But when I try to access the server I get the following error: 
"ERROR 500: Internal Server Error."

```
[root@lts5srv1 hardi]# wget mritest.domain.ch
--2012-08-23 21:51:27--  http://mritest.domain.ch/
Resolving mritest.domain.ch... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to mritest.domain.ch|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2012-08-23 21:51:27 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

So I have the connection, but I don't get any valid response.
Does it depends on the django version, should I make the deployment with Django 1.3 ?

**EDIT**

Apache error log:

```
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7835): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/django_www/hello/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] File "/home/django_www/hello/apache/django.wsgi", line 1, in <module> [Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] import os
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os"
```

Comment: Have you checked the server log to see if there was anything relevant?

Comment: Also, change `DEBUG` to `False` in `settings.py`, then reload Apache. If there's no helpful error in the logs, there will be one on the page itself with `DEBUG` enabled.

Comment: yes, in the server doesn't appear any helpful error!

Comment: @supervacuo: You probably mean to set `DEBUG`to `True`, right?

Comment: you can also set your email adress in setings.py (ADMINS, if I remember right), set debug to False and check the mail which should contain a whole traceback, but the best option is apaches error log like themanatuf suggested.

Comment: shouldn't it be a problem that the request doesn't reach Django application, because i just created a new django project just for testing..and i don't think there is any error in the django code!

Comment: @Kreshnik: What logs have you looked into? Did you see the Apache error logs? Is there something that might be related to your request?

Comment: i've checked in: "/etc/httpd/logs" > error_log.4 and sow this: "[Sun Jul 22 04:13:27 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.228] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
"

Comment: no, that wasn't the right log line: this one instead --> "[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7835): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/django_www/hello/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error]   File "/home/django_www/hello/apache/django.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error]     import os
[Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os"

Comment: why happen this -> [Thu Aug 23 22:34:04 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os"

Comment: Please check the configuration of your WSGIPythonPath as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449787/1388240

Comment: i added this : /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/python2.5/, in the variable WSGIPythonPath, but doesn't work!

Comment: it always give me an Internal Server Error

Comment: @cyroxx, please post that as an answer rather than a comment!  Kreshnik, why do you think that is the right path?  Are you trying to use a custom install of Python instead of your OS's install of Python?  What user is Apache configured to run as?  What are the permissions on that directory and its parent directories?

Comment: Please check the configuration of your WSGIPythonPath as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449787/1388240

Comment: @user9876 Added this as an answer now. Thanks for the proposal.

Comment: If you cannot get it to work then remove everything and follow the setup guide from the start.

Answer (score 2):

The mod_wsgi.so is compiled for a specific Python version. You can get this problem if you don't have that version installed or otherwise force it to use a different Python version, which cannot be done.

Work out what version of Python mod_wsgi.so is compiled for.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

So first thing to do is work out what mod_wsgi.so is compiled against.

Answer (score 0):

The web server is out of file descriptors. Use `ulimit -n` in the httpd initscript to increase the number of file descriptors allowed.